# pyScenic CLI for ctx is giving error: Not a single module loaded

Tags: python, scrnaseq, single-cell, transcriptome

Hi I ran pyScenic's ctx via the command in command prompt:

```
pyscenic ctx /home/vboxuser/pyScenic/adj.csv \
    /home/vboxuser/pyScenic/mm10__refseq-r80__10kb_up_and_down_tss.mc9nr.genes_vs_motifs.rankings.feather \
    --annotations_fname /home/vboxuser/pyScenic/motifs-v9-nr.mgi-m0.001-o0.0.tbl \
    --expression_mtx_fname /home/vboxuser/pyScenic/csk_filtered_scenic.loom \
    --mode dask_multiprocessing \
    --output reg.csv \
    --mask_dropouts \
    --num_workers 20
```

It gives me a bunch of warnings and then an error, as shown below:

```
2023-01-17 09:54:52,135 - pyscenic.cli.pyscenic - INFO - Creating modules.

2023-01-17 09:54:52,165 - pyscenic.cli.pyscenic - INFO - Loading expression matrix.

2023-01-17 09:54:55,458 - pyscenic.utils - INFO - Calculating Pearson correlations.

2023-01-17 09:54:55,482 - pyscenic.utils - WARNING - Note on correlation calculation: the default behaviour for calculating the correlations has changed after pySCENIC verion 0.9.16. Previously, the default was to calculate the correlation between a TF and target gene using only cells with non-zero expression values (mask_dropouts=True). The current default is now to use all cells to match the behavior of the R verision of SCENIC. The original settings can be retained by setting 'rho_mask_dropouts=True' in the modules_from_adjacencies function, or '--mask_dropouts' from the CLI.
    Dropout masking is currently set to [True].

2023-01-17 09:54:56,273 - pyscenic.utils - INFO - Creating modules.
/home/vboxuser/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscenic/utils.py:244: FutureWarning: Not prepending group keys to the result index of transform-like apply. In the future, the group keys will be included in the index, regardless of whether the applied function returns a like-indexed object.
To preserve the previous behavior, use

    >>> .groupby(..., group_keys=False)

To adopt the future behavior and silence this warning, use 

    >>> .groupby(..., group_keys=True)
  df = adjacencies.groupby(by=COLUMN_NAME_TARGET).apply(
/home/vboxuser/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscenic/utils.py:244: FutureWarning: Not prepending group keys to the result index of transform-like apply. In the future, the group keys will be included in the index, regardless of whether the applied function returns a like-indexed object.
To preserve the previous behavior, use

    >>> .groupby(..., group_keys=False)

To adopt the future behavior and silence this warning, use 

    >>> .groupby(..., group_keys=True)
  df = adjacencies.groupby(by=COLUMN_NAME_TARGET).apply(
/home/vboxuser/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyscenic/utils.py:244: FutureWarning: Not prepending group keys to the result index of transform-like apply. In the future, the group keys will be included in the index, regardless of whether the applied function returns a like-indexed object.
To preserve the previous behavior, use

    >>> .groupby(..., group_keys=False)

To adopt the future behavior and silence this warning, use 

    >>> .groupby(..., group_keys=True)
  df = adjacencies.groupby(by=COLUMN_NAME_TARGET).apply(

2023-01-17 09:54:56,350 - pyscenic.cli.pyscenic - ERROR - Not a single module loaded
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pyScenic, but it didn't change anything. It shouldn't be pyScenic overall either that is wrong, since I ran pyScenic grnboost command and that worked fine.

It seems like it might be specific to the pyScenic commands. Has anyone run into the same issues?

Thanks!

Comment: Background information is here https://pyscenic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html